# I can't dissolve edge on the surface

Tags: edges

[image]

Hello Bros.
Here I have problem. I made 2D mesh data.
Mesh filled by "F" and below two edges generated on the face. It's not necessary for me.

I tried "Dissolve Edges" but nothing happened.
If I tried just "delete edges", the face also deleted.

What situation am I in? Can you help?

Comment: Blender cannot create a face with a "hole" in the center without any connecting geometry, thus those edges are necessary and cannot be removed. You can form your own connections between the center hole and the outer edge, which may or may not allow you to remove the ones that are there, but there must be _some_ connection. Ideally, the whole object should be remeshed, so it is quad based (which blender prefers), because as it currently stands, the "top" and "bottom" faces of your object are massive n-gons, which can cause problems down the line with things like shading, subdividing, etc...

Comment: Christopher. Thank you for your comment. For me, It really appreciated it !! it was because I didn't design it in mesh but I imported it from 2D Illustrator vector. then, I did it converting to mesh and extrusion.
Now I learned from you that face can't support hole design.
Thanks !!!!!! again